# How to view data from wifi capture?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet, wpa

I am running wireshark on my home network to learn some things. My network is wpa and I know the key, is it possible to reconstruct the ethernet packets?

I know that after you connect to wpa there is a negotiation of a new key, I assume this is ssl or something like that where it uses a public private key mechanism so I can't see it but I wanted to make sure. if it isn't a public private key mechanism and I capture the handshake can I see the rest?

If the network was an unencrypted open network would I be able to reconstruct the communications?

Also, I am running wireshark in monitor mode so that I get the raw wifi packets. Do I have to worry about channel or does it catch all wifi over the air.

Thank you

Comment: So I could reverse the encryption if I know the key, which every user knows, is that what you are saying?

Comment: This comment would rather be on **his** answer ;) (or add @pikob for him to be notified)

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you would have to implement router's firmware in own software (cipher/decipher routines). Software that could interest you is CommView and aircrack-ng.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to worry about channel or does it catch all wifi over the
>   air.

Yes, you do have to set the channel on the adapter to the channel where you expect the traffic.